# Get remaining time when using handler.postDelayed

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I am using *handler.postDelayed* method to create some delay for some animation stuff.
Like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Start Animation.
  }
}, 6000);
```

Later, How can I get the remaining time until the animation starts?

Comment: don't understand what you want to do...

Comment: Hi, I want to know remaining time of the execution of the delayed task.

Comment: use SystemClock.uptimeMilis() to compute the time difference

Answer (score 3):

You can simply save the time in a var when you call post delayed

```
 long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 h.postDelayed(...
```

and then when you need to check the remaining time you can calculate the elapsed time like

```
 long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
```

So in your case

```
 long remainingTime = 6000 - elapsedTime;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use this to get remaining time. But, does Handler provide a convenient way to calculate remaining time?

Comment: remaining time of what?

Comment: @hemanth2081 Handler doesn't provide a method to do this in a better way.

Comment: Sometimes, _elapsedTime_ will be more than 6000(As the task is not guarantied to execute exactly after 6000 ms). In such case, _remainingTime_ will be -ve.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately with handler you don't have that kind of precision, if you need that I suggest you to take a look at Timer or AlarmManager