# Get timeout time in Handler android

Tags: android, android-handler

I have this code for my splash screen

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class));
            Log.i(TAG, "Exiting Splash Screen");
            finish();
        }
    }, TIMEOUT_TIME);
```

is it possible to get what is the current time at **TIMEOUT_TIME** from inside the run(){}?

Comment: Yes, declare it static!.

Comment: @Smashing I guess you misunderstood his question.

Comment: ahh okay, really don't think thats possible

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Handler doesn't provide any convenient method to do this. You have to save the initial time and calcualte elapsed time. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285623/975292).

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you will get current time at timeout.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Log.e("Demo","==================================="+currentDateandTime);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: not current time, the time in between the TIMEOUT_TIME and the time of starting the Handler

Comment: Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); using this line you have to get current time.you add this line in onCreate() method and also in run() method of handler.To get time difference long diffInMs = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMs)

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, I would use nanoTime() method rather than currentTimeMillis():

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
myCall(); 
long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
```